# Where can I find a list of existing Chinese surnames?

Tags: names

According to [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_surname#CITEREFEconomist1995) (reference 5), there are about 3,100 chinese surnames that are in current use.
Is there a downloadable resource that include those?

Comment: Here are more than 1000 of them: http://www.articleswriting.net/article/2430570482/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [Wiki](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B%E5%A7%93%E6%B0%8F%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8) page listed around 1,000 surnames. Origins and history of some of the surnames were provided as well.

[Here](http://expirebox.com/download/d90bbb9516bd90aa9ccfdf718d6abdf9.html) is another list I find with 3257 surnames.

Comment: The second one is great! What was the original link?

Comment: That file is from a file sharing platform. Doesn't have a real source of origins. Sorry

Comment: Second link's file expired :(

Answer (score 0):

[image: i upload the first 100 surname in China]

As you can see, this is a ranking of the first 100 surname in China in 2007.
I think it is very useful if you can learn the first 50 surname, just two rows. By the way ,my surname is 周, which is the 10th popular in China .